# Input type "file" not working in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, google-chrome-webview

I'm trying to use Android WebView, but my app can't upload an image! Basically speaking, he manages to take a picture (asks for all the permissions normally), but when he clicks to send, the sending is not carried out and the field is "blank"! Below I will leave my code. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me!

## Java

```java
package com.example.app_android_5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null){
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if(mCM != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        assert webView != null;
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if(mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try{
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if(photoFile != null){
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    }else{
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if(takePictureIntent != null){
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                }else{
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack()){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

## AndroidManifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App_android_5"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've already looked in different forums and publications, but, as I still don't know very well how development using Android works, I couldn't reach this answer. Currently I've tested it with Android 5.0, 5.1, 8, 11 and 12, but it still doesn't work!